# Collection<Sub> casted as SuperCollection<Super>

Tags: java, casting

In java one can cast instance of a class `B` into an instance of class `A` provided that `B` extends `A`.

Can this be done also for type-parametrized classes? For instance, for `B` extending `A`, I'd like to do the following:

```
List<A> l = new ArrayList<B>();
```

I think this should be legal, but the compiler doesn't agree with me on this point, so I tricked it with the following hack:

```
List<A> l = (List<A>)(List) new ArrayList<B>();
```

…but I think that I'll be hit by a [velociraptor](https://xkcd.com/292/). Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Fortunately, it's not legal.        ( (List<Object>)new ArrayList<String> ) .add(new NotAString());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think this should be legal, but the compiler doesn't agree with me on this point

Generally, when humans and compilers disagree, it is safe to take the compiler's side. Instead of tricking the compiler, you should first understand why it does not allow the conversion.

Consider this: you make a `List<B>`, like this:

```
List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Everyone is happy so far. Now let's do what you think is correct:

```
// This does not compile, but let's pretend that it does
List<A> listA = (List<A>)listB;
```

At this point, we have `listA` that is entirely ours! Let's play with it: let's say we have another class `C` extending `A`. Can we do this?

```
listA.add(new C()); // Why not? The compiler should allow it!
```

But wait, do you see what we have done? Our `listB` contains a `C` now! This is why the compiler does not allow the conversion; this is also why your code is not safe in cases when you attempt to add anything to the list.

To work around this issue, you can use wildcards: `List<? extends A>`.  However, this will limit your lists to read-only access. If you must allow writing (and you know that you are going to set only the right stuff) use the non-generic `List` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<? extends A> l = new ArrayList<B>();
```

You should read about generics in java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it.......

**-** This way of handling the `Collections` are done, cause `Array` is **checked during compile and as well as runtime**, but `Collections` are checked only during `Compile time`.

**-** So there should **NOT be an accidental addition of another type of object in to another type of Collection**, ie Dog Object into a Cat Collection.

**1.**

```
public <T extends A> void go(ArrayList<T> aList){


}
```

**2.**

```
public void go(ArrayList<? extends A> aList){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a non generic context, if B "is a" A, then B can be substituted for A, but A cannot be substituted for B.

With generics, List and List are both "is a" `Collection<E>`; that is, List is not a subclass of List, and therefore, you cannot substitute List for List.

The specific content on generics you're looking for can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), copied below for your convenience.

> Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer), MyClass has no relationship to MyClass, regardless of whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of MyClass and MyClass is Object.